# Removing \t\t\t from sample\t\t

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i am using js and i want to remove \t\t\t from my result.

I have tried Regex ... it not working.

Comment: Post the code you are using, what you have, what you are getting and what do you want. `it not working` is a little bit vague.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: -value - vVal = saple\t\t
-regex- vVal = namere.replace(/\t+/g, "");
-result- saple\t\t

Comment: update your question with your code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/\t/g, "");
```

The g flag will search for the \t globally.